# Unintentional Swift struct copy and destroy

Tags: ios, swift, struct, unboxing

Can you help me find out why unboxing and accessing a property of a swift struct would lead to a copy and destroy of said struct? The struct is quite large, and since this happens in a loop, this unexpected behaviour drains quite a bit of performance.

A co-worker and I have written an open source library [SnapPageableArray](https://github.com/skylib/SnapPageableArray) that contains an Example project that exhibits this behaviour. The example uses the SnapPageableArray as a data set backing a collection view, and every 5 seconds it [adds a bit more data](https://github.com/skylib/SnapPageableArray/blob/master/Example/ViewController.swift#L21). According to Instruments, the topup causes [line 50 of PageableArray](https://github.com/skylib/SnapPageableArray/blob/master/SnapPageableArray/PageableArray.swift#L50) to take a very long time, and it indicates that at this place LocalData is copied and destroyed:

[image: Code from Instruments]
[image: Trace from Instruments]
([full Instruments screen here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tkorukcku1bpy0l/FullInstrumentsScreen.png?dl=0))

[self.elements](https://github.com/skylib/SnapPageableArray/blob/master/SnapPageableArray/PageableArray.swift#L7) is an array of the class [ElementWithState<T>](https://github.com/skylib/SnapPageableArray/blob/master/SnapPageableArray/ElementWithState.swift) where T is my struct LocalData, and the properties in ElementWithState are a state enum and the element in question (the LocalData struct).

Why is my struct copied? I unbox and look up references only, there is no assignment, right?

What can I do to avoid the copying and following destruction?

A few PS'es:

- [LocalData](https://github.com/skylib/SnapPageableArray/blob/master/Example/LocalData.swift) is a large struct equal to structs we use in our app. We
  would like to not convert it into a class as the struct is a better
  fit for the rest of our application
- The full Instruments trace is [available here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yzqnjrwy4kdx3s5/Instruments8.trace.zip?dl=0)
- The trace was done using an iPhone 5, but the issue is there just as much on the iPhone 6S and iPad Pro